# Telegram groups, supergroups, and channels

Tags: whatsapp, telegram, instant-messaging

- I'm new to Telegram. I need a clarification about one of the features of Telegram.
- After creating groups or channels in Telegram, is there a way to know which recipients have received the message, and which recipients have actually read the message?
- I know this functionality is available in Whatsapp, I was wondering whether Telegram also provide this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

No telegram doesn't have that functionality yet. The moment you send a message to either a group, supergroup or channel, it is perceived as sent and read, however channels show you the actual number of people who have read the message.

You can however see the most active users by time spent on a supergroup using a third-party bot like ComStatbot.

Normal groups on telegram are the equivalent to Whats App groups. I recommend you to always convert to supergroup due to more functions.